# android read SMS Inbox messages

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I write a program to read android phone sms records. The like this:

```
    package com.example.read_sms;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
                    null);
            String sms = "";
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                sms += "From :"
                        + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))
                        + " : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")) + "\n";
            }
            textView.setText(sms);
        }

    }
```

I run this on a emulator, the emulator run on my goldfish kernel. I insert a kernel to hook read sms, the code like this:

```
asmlinkage int our_sys_open(const char* file, int flags, int mode)
{
//联系人 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db            //通话记录                 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
 //短信记录  /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
  char * contact =        "/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db";
  char * telephony =     "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db";
  char * sms = "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db";
if (strcmp(file, contact) == 0){
  printk("应用程序正在读取手机的联系人记录！！！\n");
 }
if (strcmp(file, telephony) == 0){
 printk("应用程序正在读取手机的通话记录！！！\n");
}
if (strcmp(file, sms) == 0){
 printk("应用程序正在读取手机的短信记录！！！\n");
}


 // printk("A file was opened\n%s\n%d\n%d\n",file,flags,mode);
 return original_call_open(file, flags, mode);
}
```

Above is my own hook function, I across "cat /proc/kmsg" to look kernel info.
When i install this apk, the kernel show 
"应用程序正在读取手机的联系人记录！！！"
“/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db-mj4dec6bdb”
"应用程序的名称是ContactsProvide"
"该应用程序的进程id是：222"
I don't know why the kernel show "...contacts.db....", but I read sms. In my opinion it should show "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db....". Can anybody help me?THX.

Comment: Please test it on real device. Emulator is not right choice.

Comment: if i test this program in real device, i need to downloads its kernel and compile it. It is so complex, do you answer me why it occurs like this? thanks.@waheedakhtar

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    // List required columns
    String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

    // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
    bankMessage = new ArrayList<message>();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("address", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")).contains("SBI") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")).contains("HDFC") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")).contains("ICICI")){
            message bMessage = new message();
            bMessage.set_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            bMessage.setAddress(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));
            bMessage.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")));
            bankMessage.add(bMessage);
        }
    }
    // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
            new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
            R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
    lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you should also try to explain with words what your code does and how it solves the OP problem